# (Tabulator) How can I remove unwanted newline from string when pasting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator >> [link](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9) 
How to remove unwanted newline in string when pasting the data copied from Excel sheet?

This is my data in Excel sheet

[image]

And this is the current result

[image]

I would like the result to show like this

[image]

This is my current code

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script>
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205,
        layout:"fitColumns", 
        columns:[ 
            {title:"A", field:"A"},
            {title:"B", field:"B"},
            {title:"C", field:"C"},
            {title:"D", field:"D"},
        ],
        clipboard:"paste", 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: are you copying and pasting just one cell or an entire table?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it by adding custom manipulation to remove unwanted newlines when pasting data into the table.
Here's the code

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:205,
        layout:"fitData",
        columns:col_list,
        clipboard:true,
        clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
        clipboardPasteParser:function(clipboard){
            clipboard = JSON.stringify(clipboard);
            clipboard = clipboard.replace(/\\n/g,"");
            clipboard = clipboard.replace(/\\r/g,"\r\n");

            var data = clipboard.split('\r\n').map(function(ln){
                return ln.split("\\t");
            });
            data.splice(-1,1)
           
            var new_data = [];
            $.each( data, function( index,val ) {
                var obj = {};
                for(var i=0; i<73; i++){
                    var col = col_list[i].title;
                    obj[col] = val[i];
                }
                new_data.push(obj);
            });
            table.addData(new_data);
        }
    });
```